# Activesync: If I disable or rename the AD account does that mean the phone won't be wiped?

Tags: email, mobile, risk-management, active-directory, iphone

Suppose an Activesync phone needs to be wiped because it was lost, stolen, or it was an employee termination.

If we disable the account prior to wiping the device (or the device receiving the wipe command) does that mean the device may not be erased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no if the phone is set up using username and password, then the phone will not get wiped.

I haven't tested certificate-based authentication and welcome the experience of anyone here who has.  (tell me what happens....)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the wipe is unrelated to the user account, as the phone itself is now tied to Exchange.